# how to match a string allowed "-" appear multiple times with python re?

Tags: python, string, python-re

I have a protein sequence:

`seq = "EIVL**TQSPG**TLSLSRA**SQS---VS**SSYLAWYQQKPG"

and i want to match two type regions/strings:

the first type is continuous,like `TQSPG` in **seq**.

the second type we only know the continuous form, but in fact there may be multiple "-" characters in the middle,for example what i know is  `SQSVS`, but in seq it is **SQS---VS**.

what i want to do is to match these two type of string and get the index, forexample `TQSPG` is `(4,9)`, and for `SQSVS` is (16,24).

I tried use `re.search('TQSPG',seq).span()`, it return `(4,9)`, but i don't konw how to deal the second type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order of `SQSVS` needs to be preserved, I'd propose the regex `r'S-*Q-*S-*V-*S'`. This will match the sequence `SQSVS` with any number (might be 0) of hyphens included between either of the letters.

Answer (score 0):

`re.search(r'([SQVS]+-*[SQVS]+)', seq).span()`

Assuming that the '-' can will be between the first and last character